# Why does Python's calculation of variance not include Bessel's correction?

Tags: python, variance

I'm a little confused by Python's calculation of variance. The results below show that  variance calculated manually without Bessel's correction ("len(nums)" rather than "len(nums)-1")  returns the same result as numpy's builtin var() function. Can anyone explain why this is?

```
# Create a sample list
import math
import numpy as np
nums = list(range(101))

# Compute the mean of the list
mean = np.mean(nums)

# Compute the variance manually
variance = sum(pow(x - mean, 2) for x in nums) / len(nums)
print (variance)
    
# Compute and print using var()
np_variance = np.array(nums).var()
print(np_variance)
```

Edit: I was under the impression the variance formula should use *n-1* (Bessel's correction) in the denominator rather than just *n* (represented by *len(nums)* here). It looks like this alternative method that doesn't use Bessel's correction is the same as the one the builtin function uses, which doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: What is it you don't understand? You seem to have figured out what is going on.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear; in the manual computation, I'm confused as to why the denominator is not len(nums) - 1, which is what I thought the variance formula used. Furthermore, it seems that len(nums) is also used as the demoninator in the built in variance function.

Comment: **You can tell it what value to use**. By default, the ddof is 0, so you get the *population variance*. Did you read the documentation?

Comment: Ah, okay that makes sense; I forgot that Bessel's only applies to sample variance. Much thanks for your help!